# React apollo query too damn fast

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I have a react apollo query that is too fast. The `<p>Loading...</p>` is shown for a split second before the api query finishes and my results are shown. Is there any way to slow this down or produce a slight delay to prevent this flash of content?

Comment: It's a good thing that it's fast. You could have a timeout of e.g. 300ms that will set `loading` to `true` in your component, so that it will not be shown if your network request is fast.

Comment: Why not do the opposite? Don't show your loading message unless the query takes longer than expected. You say it is almost instant, so perhaps show the loading message after, say, 200ms? Should "feel" instant to the user while still preventing the flash on a good connection.

Comment: @Tholle that's an interesting idea but how would you stop setting `loading` to `true` once you know you have received the data? directly doing this would just set `loading` to `true` everytime since the code that sets `loading` to `false` would be executed before the delayed assignment of loading to true.

Comment: Imo, don't show loading state, it will only confuse users. As what @Chris said, you could implement loading message after x period of time.

Comment: @ManavM Yes, you also need some indicator if the request itself has finished for it to work properly.

Comment: @ManavM you can easily do this with a third state. For example `null` for yet not loaded, `true` for loaded and `false` for explicitly set to false. You can then check against those values. Alternatively a second variable that always keeps the previous value. You can then check against that.

Comment: @Chris just to clarify you're saying we set something like `loaded: true` when the request has loaded and if at that point `loading` is `true` we set it to `false`. And as for setting `loading` we first check whether `loaded` is already `true`? It's a little twisted but it feels like it would work, thanks.

Comment: @ManavM something like that, yes. Depends on the implementation details of the app of course. If it feels weird, one can always use two variables instead.

Comment: Trigger two actions. One from successful request and one from `setTimeout`. Wait for both. If the request is fast, you will wait for timeout. If not, you will just wait for request, without additional delay.

Comment: @Sulthan That wont work..JS is asynchronous and therefore "Waiting" for an action is not really something that can be done realistically

Comment: @Chris This entire thing feels like it should be a more common occurrence, yet I couldn't find any questions relating to that on SO. I think I might either edit this into one, or make my own post.

Comment: @ManaM What I mean by "waiting" is that you have two boolean variables in your state, e.g `pendingRequest` and `pendingTimeout` and you display loading when one of them is `true`. Please, don't explain to me the nature of JS (it is a strange thing to say JS is asynchronous).

Comment: @Sulthan taking offence to something this mild will make your internet experience very unsatisfying indeed sir.

Comment: https://disjoint.ca/til/2017/09/21/how-to-delay-the-display-of-loading-animations-in-react/ looks like the issue has been addressed, just not on SO. @thatnzguy this should solve your issue.

Comment: @ManavM The example is good, only show the loading if the query takes longer than 250ms. But what if the query comes back at 251ms?

Comment: @thatnzguy please note that it is not my example but the blogger's, I don't want to take credit for someone else's work. As for the example, it is an arbitrary line that you have to set for yourself. What do you think is too fast? What will feel like a flash and not like a loading screen? Personally I feel anything longer than 500ms should be shown with a loading component as it is long enough for my eyes to register it, but that is more of a personal opinion than an objective answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in Apollo client that lets you do this.

I guess what you want is to display the `Loading` placeholder only if the content is too long to display. In addition to avoid the flashing of content you describe, you avoid that *perceptual* performance issue (ie. users will more likely *feel* something is slow, if there's a `Loading...` caption, even if it takes the same time)

What you can do?

### Solution 1: Use local state

- Add a `showLoading` state variable in addition to loading prop from Apollo
- Only trigger `showLoading` state if it's been too long

Code example (with a component that already receives the `loading` prop from Apollo) - to adapt to your own use case...

```
const SHOW_LOADING_AFTER = 1000

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showLoading: false
    }
    this.loadingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ showLoading: true })
    }, SHOW_LOADING_AFTER)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.loadingTimeout)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return this.state.showLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : null
    }
    return <p>Ready!</p>
  }
}
```

### Solution 2

Make this generic with a higher order component, or a `<Timeout>` component wrapping `<p>Loading...</p>` in the render method to avoid polluting state.

All you would need would be in your render method:

```
if (this.props.loading) {
  <Timeout ms={SHOW_LOADING_AFTER}><p>Loading...</p></Timeout>
}
```

Comment: This would be very simpler with redux-observable actually.

Comment: This feels like it is really off-topic, the OP seems to be asking how to not show the loading text if the request happens very fast because in that instance the screen will just look like it flashed for no reason.

Comment: @ManavM I forgot a case in the render method indeed. Other than that, the code does what the OP wants: show nothing instead of `Loading...` before `SHOW_LOADING_DELAY`, only IF data is not yet loaded, then after this delay, start displaying `Loading...` if data still isn't loaded yet. Am I missing something? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Edit: edited the code to be more declarative / simple

Comment: @Pandaiolo this is another way to approach the problem, certainly...so I'm removing my downvote, especially since the answer has been edited to be a lot more usable.

Comment: @Pandaiolo Although, I would encourage you to look at [this blog post](https://disjoint.ca/til/2017/09/21/how-to-delay-the-display-of-loading-animations-in-react/), I think it's a very broad solution that can be inserted anywhere (regardles of whether your query returns a `loading` prop).

Comment: Yep, I was just reading this while looking for a `Timeout` implementation suggested in my `Solution 2`, I think it is similar. (But did not find a generic npm package..) Also makes me think of future react API like suspense https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6iR3Zk4oDY